# How to know whether alert dialog is displaying on screen or not without having instance?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to know whether alert dialog is displaying on screen or not without having instance ?

`private fun showAlertDialog() { val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity) builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit ?") builder.setTitle("Alert !") builder.setCancelable(false) builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int -> finish() } as DialogInterface.OnClickListener) builder.setNegativeButton("No", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int -> dialog.cancel() } as DialogInterface.OnClickListener) val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create() alertDialog.show() }`

Comment: An alternative wording of the question could be _"How to find an AlertDialog with the tag?"_ and a possible solution could be `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`, but I didn't really try this out and won't post a proper answer. Just be careful to use the correct `FragmentManager` i.e. the one used in `dialog.show()`. This is covered in more detail in [https://medium.com/@uyaribrahim/android-alertdialog-everything-you-need-to-know-553fbf8dfb08](https://medium.com/@uyaribrahim/android-alertdialog-everything-you-need-to-know-553fbf8dfb08)

Comment: The `Dialog` class then has an `isShowing()` method that can be called on the instance.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about wording , I am using the simple alert dialog creation like mentioned in the description